# Extracting shape information from Visio xml files in Python for graph computation and chatbot creation with langchain

Tags: xml-parsing, visio, py-langchain

How can I read the activities, arrows and teams in a visio cross functional diagram using python?  I want to be able to pass this information to langchain to be able to create a chatbot based on the process map.

I have managed to extract the underlying xml files for the vsdx file, but am not sure how to read these to extract the activity, arrows and team information.  The idea is to be able to use these to also programatically create a graph and compute the DFS of the graph.

I did manage to extract the xml files using xml.etree.ElementTree, but I do not know how to extract the relevant shape information from here.